# Icons not showing in react when using material-icons using cdn instead showing their text

Tags: reactjs, icons, cdn

I am using react with material-icons without npm as I am using cdn link .
Now I have saved their tags in a external file and calling them in a component but instead of showing icons they are showing their text.
This is my array that I am calling

```
 export const LeftbarTop = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Apps",
  icon:<span className="material-icons-outlined">
        widgets
        </span>,
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Help",
  icon: <span className="material-icons-outlined">
        help_outline
        </span>,
},
```

];

This is my component through which I am calling this file/array

```
import {LeftbarTop} from '../../data/sidebar_activity'
```

function Leftbar(){

```
const arr = [...LeftbarTop];

return (<>
    <div className="leftbar">
        <div className="leftbar-topbar">
            {arr.map(ele => <LeftList arr={ele}/>)}
        </div>
        <div className="leftbar-bottombar"></div>
    </div>
</>)
```

}

this is my LeftList component that simply shows that data

function LeftList ({arr}){

```
return (
    <div >
       <div >{arr.icon}</div>
        {arr.name && <label>{arr.name}</label>}
    </div>
)
```

}

this whole shows icons as

```
widgets Apps
help_outline Help
```

Comment: What do you mean by saving their tags in an external file ? Can you share the content of that file as well ?